# using templates to apply class functions to a vector of objects

Tags: c++, object, templating

Lets say I have vectors of different objects, say `D` is of type `vector< Dog >` and `R` is of type `vector< Rock >`. Is it possible to use templates so I can automatically have all member functions be callable on the vectors? I.e. if `Dog` has a function `Bark()`, I want `D.bark()` to cause all the dogs to bark.

Now, clearly I could code this behavior by hand with a new function and a simple loop, but is
there an easy way to template it? I.e. so that `R.smash()` smashes all the rocks without me
ever explicitly coding that loop. I'm trying to imagine what the syntax would be and it is blowing my mind.

Comment: The loop itself has to be coded, there is no way to take any action on each object in a vector without some sort of loop.

Comment: How sad! I wish there were some way of functional templating such that the function coming after the . got passed in as an argument which could then be automatically called in a loop in the template function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::for_each(dogs.begin(), dogs.end(), std::bind(&Dog::bark, _1));
```

In C++03, you can use `boost::bind` instead. You can try to wrap it in a separate function template, but I have a feeling it won't buy you much. Using `for_each` where you need this behaviour is clear enough.

Comment: Thanks. The bind command looks like the key here. I'll read up on it.

Comment: This is the best approach, but it still is "coding the loop".

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work:

```
std::for_each(dog_vec.begin(),dog_vec.end(),std::mem_fun_ref(&dog::bark));
```

I think there's an easier way.

Comment: Note that `mem_fun_ref` is deprecated in C++11.